# Asp.net MVC web site on iis goes idle after few minutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, task

I have an asp.net mvc 5 site running on iis. In the `Application_Start` I have a call to this method called `Run();`.

```
private void Run()
{
    Task t = new Task(() => new XyzServices().ProcessXyz());
    t.Start();
    t.ContinueWith((x) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(ConfigReader.CronReRunTimeInSeconds);
        Run();
    });
}
```

I am running a task which process some data, and as soon as the task completes I wait fr 20-30 seconds and rerun the task again.

Now all this works fine. But after a certain time, the process stops and its resumes only when I reopen the site url.

How do I overcome this ? Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: where do you start 't' Task?

Comment: is windows service not a better option for this?

Comment: Sorry, @lukbl i had renamed the variable but had not updated my code.

Comment: @Krishna yes eventually it ll move there.. but as of now its this way. Since I need to trigger this fr incoming web hooks too.

Comment: and are you sure, you are sleeping for 20 to 30 "seconds" and not minutes, IIS app pools shutdown at default idle 20 minutes,

Comment: @Krishna Yes. its 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your application pool is shutdown automatically

1) Open IIS.

2) Right click on your Application-Pool for the web application and select "Advanced Settings".

3) Set "Rapid-Fail Protection" -> "Enabled" to False.

If this is true, the Application pool is shut down if there are a specified number of worker process crashes within a specified time period. By default, an application pool is shutdown if there are 5 crashes within a 5 minutes interval.

for more info https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22885/application-pool-is-auto-stopped-when-browse-web-application-in-iis7]

Comment: I am sure there is no exception. I have elmah too on the site, I dont see any errors there.